# Getting a Parse Error Expecting a Type

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using the following code to create a static method to return the DashboardMainMenuViewController. In the interface .h file I get an error saying that expecting type.

```
+(DashboardMainMenuViewController *) dashboardMainMenuController;

+(DashboardMainMenuViewController *) dashboardMainMenuController
{
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *) [[[self appDelegate] window] rootViewController];

    NSArray *navigationControllers = [splitViewController viewControllers];

    NSArray *viewControllers = [[navigationControllers objectAtIndex:0] viewControllers];

    return (DashboardMainMenuViewController *) [viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

Comment: azamsharp, in what .h file are you getting the error? Is the code above in the same file - I would expect the 1st line to be in a .h and the rest to be in a .m file... On what line are you getting the error? So many questions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either `#import "DashboardMainMenuViewController.h"` or declare a forward reference to it with `@class DashboardMainMenuViewController`.  The compiler is only aware of the types defined in imported headers or those that are forward-declared

Comment: I have the import DashboardMainMenuViewController.h

Comment: Weird!! I removed the .h file and added the @class and it worked!